# Extract 'Status': 'COMPLIANT' from the below response/output

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Extract 'Status': 'COMPLIANT' from the below response/output

[{'ComplianceType': 'Association', 'ResourceType': 'ManagedInstance', 'ResourceId': 'i-044b91e7e4ee09a45', 'Id': '06f4ff2d-c014-4a95-b569-2afa64246c8d', 'Title': '', 'Status': 'COMPLIANT', 'Severity': 'HIGH', 'ExecutionSummary': {'ExecutionTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24, 14, 39, 31, tzinfo=tzlocal())}, 'Details': {'DocumentName': 'AWS-RunPatchBaseline', 'DocumentVersion': '1'}}, {'ComplianceType': 'Patch', 'ResourceType': 'ManagedInstance', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxx', 'Id': 'bind-export-libs.x86_64', 'Title': 'bind-export-libs.x86_64:32:9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5', 'Status': 'COMPLIANT', 'Severity': 'UNSPECIFIED', 'ExecutionSummary': {'ExecutionTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24, 14, 33, 23, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ExecutionId': 'cfbcac2b-c4c5-4e73-99bb-c39208ccdda8', 'ExecutionType': 'Command'}, 'Details': {'Classification': 'Security', 'InstalledTime': '2021-09-24T09:02:00Z', 'PatchBaselineId': 'pb-0e930e75b392d70da', 'PatchSeverity': 'Important', 'PatchState': 'Installed'}}, {'ComplianceType': 'Patch', 'ResourceType': 'ManagedInstance', 'ResourceId': 'i-044b91e7e4ee09a45', 'Id': 'bind-libs.x86_64', 'Title': 'bind-libs.x86_64:32:9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5', 'Status': 'COMPLIANT', 'Severity': 'UNSPECIFIED', 'ExecutionSummary': {'ExecutionTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24, 14, 33, 23, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ExecutionId': 'cfbcac2b-c4c5-4e73-99bb-c39208ccdda8', 'ExecutionType': 'Command'}, 'Details': {'Classification': 'Security', 'InstalledTime': '2021-09-24T09:01:59Z', 'PatchBaselineId': 'pb-0e930e75b392d70da', 'PatchSeverity': 'Important', 'PatchState': 'Installed'}}, {'ComplianceType': 'Patch', 'ResourceType': 'ManagedInstance', 'ResourceId': 'i-044b91e7e4ee09a45', 'Id': 'bind-libs-lite.x86_64', 'Title': 'bind-libs-lite.x86_64:32:9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5', 'Status': 'COMPLIANT', 'Severity': 'UNSPECIFIED', 'ExecutionSummary': {'ExecutionTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24, 14, 33, 23, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ExecutionId': 'cfbcac2b-c4c5-4e73-99bb-c39208ccdda8', 'ExecutionType': 'Command'}, 'Details': {'Classification': 'Security', 'InstalledTime': '2021-09-24T09:01:59Z', 'PatchBaselineId': 'pb-0e930e75b392d70da', 'PatchSeverity': 'Important', 'PatchState': 'Installed'}}, {'ComplianceType': 'Patch', 'ResourceType': 'ManagedInstance', 'ResourceId': 'i-xxxxxxx', 'Id': 'bind-license.noarch', 'Title': 'bind-license.noarch:32:9.11.4-26.P2.amzn2.5', 'Status': 'COMPLIANT', 'Severity': 'UNSPECIFIED', 'ExecutionSummary': {'ExecutionTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 24, 14, 33, 23, tzinfo=tzlocal()), 'ExecutionId': 'cfbcac2b-c4c5-4e73-99bb-c39208ccdda8', 'ExecutionType': 'Command'}, 'Details': {'Classification': 'Security', 'InstalledTime': '2021-09-24T09:01:59Z', 'PatchBaselineId': 'pb-0e930e75b392d70da', 'PatchSeverity': 'Important', 'PatchState': 'Installed'}},

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
ssm_client = boto3.client('ssm')
reservations = client.describe_instances().get("Reservations", None)
instances = []
INSTANCE_ID_KEY = "InstanceId"
for reservation in reservations:
    instances.extend(reservation.get("Instances", None))
    #print(reservation)

for instance in instances:
    #print(instance[INSTANCE_ID_KEY])
    ssm_resp = ssm_client.list_compliance_items(ResourceIds=[instance[INSTANCE_ID_KEY]],ResourceTypes=['ManagedInstance'])
    #print(ssm_resp)
    L1=ssm_resp['ComplianceItems']
    
    print(L1)
    print("\n")
    D1={}
    D1=L1
    D1=L1[0]
    print(D1['Status'])
    '''


Please help or guide me on this .
```

Answer (score 0):

If L1 is what you posted. It looks like you have a list with dicts.
so maybe something like this:

```
for item in L1:
   status = item["Status"]
```

But testting this:

```
L1=ssm_resp['ComplianceItems'] 
print(L1) 
print("\n") 
D1={} 
D1=L1 #Isn't needed we you are resetting D1 on the next line 
D1=L1[0] 
print(D1['Status'])
```

It works for me. So what error do you get? Is you Lambda timing out?